# How do leaders gain experience?

Tags: stellaris

Some of my governors reach rank 5, while others die at rank 1 after decades of managing a colony or a sector. What are the different ways leaders gain experience and how much of it do they get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from the `00_defines.lua` within the Stellaris folder, I found these values:

#### Governors

- Clearing a Tile / Constructing a building gives 50% of the resources spent building or clearing.
- Having a planetary edict gives 5% of the Edict's cost each month the edict is active
- 8 exp for each Pop born
- 3.5 exp each month for governing a Sector

#### Scientists

- 350% bonus xp if researching within the field of their expertise
- 18 xp per planet surveyed
- 100 xp for discovering an anomaly
- 100 xp from completing a special project (in addition to the XP special projects can reward themselves)
- .35 xp * scientist level / day of "Assist Research"

#### Admirals & Generals

Admirals & Generals gain XP based on the ships / armies killed & lost, though the define doesn't have exact formulas. I'd wager Military power for fleets, but not sure how Army XP might be calculated.

I'm guessing that cost-reducing effects reduce experience gain as well, though that probably warrants more testing.

Comment: How much for doing research?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much about governor and how they earn experience since most of my time were spent surveying and manage research. Even when I manage planets I just look at the building tile screen and don't pay attention to Governor.

That said I assume most of the experience would come from building stuff. Because I notice that level up occur when a building/upgrade is done.

Furthermore if you have trouble giving your governor more experience. You can research technologies to raise your leaders overall lifetime (chance of dying young goes down).

Comment: Yep, to put it in as few words possible: governor - buildin', scientist researchin' and surveyin', admiral & genral fightin'. That said @kotekzot, if your governors die at rank 1 after managing a SECTOR for decades, something is seriously wrong with your sector, this would indicate pretty much noch activity within the sector.